# How to display a notification that a bot has stopped working?

Tags: python, discord

@ client.event

async def on_ready ():
print ('Bot is connected')

Indicates that the bot has started working. How do you do the opposite?

Comment: That's not possible

Comment: There is an `on_disconnect` event, is that what you are talking about? [on_disconnect](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_disconnect)